# AttributeError: 'socket' object has no attribute 'recive'

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I have been working on a project with a raspberry pi. I'm trying to communicate between the laptop and the raspberry pi using sockets.

I was trying a youtube tutorial and keep getting this error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    s.recive(1024)
AttributeError: 'socket' object has no attribute 'recive'

after failing to run the script I tried typing the code line by line on python shell

import socket
socket.recv(1024)

but still getting the same error

Can anyone explain whats the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mind first reading the api and examples?
The correct syntax is `buffer = socket.recv(1024)`
as noted at [socket — Low-level networking interface](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv)

But also it seems you are missing other basic flow, like the fact that you have to create the connection first.

Take some time first reading examples of the right use of sockets and then start coding.
A good start would be [TutorialsPoint - Python 3 - Network Programming](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_networking.htm)

Comment: Sorry.. My bad. I'm just a beginner. Thanks for your effort... I will refer the TutorialsPoint - Python 3 - Network Programming
Thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with the help of tutorialspoint.com

**Simple server**

```
    #!/usr/bin/python3           # This is server.py file
    import socket                                         

    # create a socket object
    serversocket = socket.socket(
                socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 

    # get local machine name
    host = socket.gethostname()                           

    port = 9999                                           

    # bind to the port
    serversocket.bind((host, port))                                  

    # queue up to 5 requests
    serversocket.listen(5)                                           

    while True:
       # establish a connection
       clientsocket,addr = serversocket.accept()      

       print("Got a connection from %s" % str(addr))

       msg = 'Thank you for connecting'+ "\r\n"
       clientsocket.send(msg.encode('ascii'))
       clientsocket.close()
```

**Simple client**

```
# create a socket object
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 

# get local machine name
host = socket.gethostname()                           

port = 9999

# connection to hostname on the port.
s.connect((host, port))                               

# Receive no more than 1024 bytes
msg = s.recv(1024)                                     

s.close()
print (msg.decode('ascii'))
```